# I need to get the user id from my users table in DynamoDB?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS Amplify on my react native app

I want to do something seemingly so simple, but i am a bit lost as to how to do it: I have a table with user information already in it. Here's the Schema:

```
type Users @model {
  id: ID!
  userName: String
  firstname: String
  weblink: String
  email: String
  mobileNum: String
 .
 .
 .
}


//Here's my Query.js
export const getUsers = `query GetUsers($id: ID!) {
  getUsers(id: $id) {
    id
    userName
    firstname
    weblink
    email
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
`;
```

This table is populated in DynamoDB when i check my AWS console. What i need is to be able to get the id from the table using the userName (not vice versa). The id is generated when i createUser() and it's used throughout my app to get all my user's information. However when a user signs in on a new phone, this id isn't available anymore. So when they sign in via Cognito, i do know the userName and all i need to do is retrieve this id.

Normally i would do this, but obviously i want to do the reverse and use my unique userName to get the id:

```
const userData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(GetUsers, { id: usersId }));   //usersId = "3b0dae-24j5-4401-95a6-11seyhaf1g131"
```

Any idea how i can get my users id?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `userName` is unique, create a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) with `userName` as the partition key. [Project](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections), at least, the `id` attribute into the index. Finally, search that index instead of the underlying table.

Alternatively, if you *never* need to lookup by `id`, consider making `userName` the partition key and `id` a regular attribute.

Comment: How do i create or set userName as a GSI? Wont i have to create a completely new table?

Comment: The process is pretty simple and well documented. The AWS console is helpful too. You simply have to create a GSI, indicate its partition key, and indicate which attributes to project. Then change your query from the native table to the table/gsi (how you do that depends on which SDK you're using, but typically you indicate the TableName and the IndexName).